# Cordova / Ionic - Download file from InAppBrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

The scenario goes like this: I open a website in InAppBrowser, after the user ends with the work over there, the site generates a .pdf for the user to download, the problem is that the pdf does not download, it opens it in the browser.

Is there a way to make it download from the InAppBrowser? I'm currently working on an iOS app, so the solution would be better for iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the user is redirected to a .pdf file or a different url from the one where the user did his work, it might be possible to use the loadstart event to detect the url of the .pdf and then use filetransfer plugin to download, or use inAppBrowser with _system option that will open safari and safari will show an "open with" message where the user can open the pdf with any app that supports pdf files

Comment: The website presents a button to download the .pdf file, when the user touches that button the pdf is then opened in `InAppBrowser`. I'll try to add the `loadstart` event solution and get back to you. I guess if it works i'll also have to deal with the window viewing the pdf. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: if you detect the pdf url on the loadstart then you can use ref.close(); to close the inAppBrowser window once you start the download

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following @jcesarmobile advices this is what I came up with:

First I had to install the [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

#### Open URL

```
var url = "http://mi-fancy-url.com";
var windowref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Cerrar,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

#### Create a listener on that `windowref` for a `loadstart` event and check if what's being loaded is a pdf (that's my case).

```
windowref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
  var url = e.url;
  var extension = url.substr(url.length - 4);
  if (extension == '.pdf') {
    var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "receipt.pdf";
    var options = {};
    var args = {
      url: url,
      targetPath: targetPath,
      options: options
    };
    windowref.close(); // close window or you get exception
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
        downloadReceipt(args); // call the function which will download the file 1s after the window is closed, just in case..
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

#### Create the function that will handle the file download and then open it:

```
function downloadReceipt(args) {
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var uri = encodeURI(args.url);

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri, // file's uri
    args.targetPath, // where will be saved
    function(entry) {
      console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
      window.open(entry.toURL(), '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Cerrar,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes');
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("download error source " + error.source);
      console.log("download error target " + error.target);
      console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    true,
    args.options
  );
}
```

The problem i'm facing now is the path where it downloads, I just can't open it. But well, at least file is now downloaded. I will have to create a localStorage item to save the paths for different files.

Many validations are missing in this steps, this was just an example I made quickly to check if it works. Further validations are needed.

Comment: @João Pimentel Ferreira why the edit changing $timeout to setTimeout? $timeout is an angularjs service, a wrapper for the setTimeout fn but running inside angularjs's scope.

Comment: ah ok, it's because that is not available in pure Cordova and `setTimeout` is plain vanilla Javascript

Comment: Yeah, but this is not for vanilla js, its for ionic1, which uses angularjs, hence the $timeout instead of setTimeout :)

Comment: ok, but ionic is based on Cordova, and there are many projects in cordova that do not use ionic

Answer (score 0):

1. Open you window using IAB plugin and add an event listener 
   ref = window.open(url, "_blank");
   ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadStopCallBack);
2. In the InAppBrowser window call the action using https://xxx.pdf">documentName
3. Implement the loadStopCallBack function

   ```
   function loadStopCallBack(refTemp) {
       if(refTemp.url.includes('downloadDoc')) {
           rtaParam = getURLParams('downloadDoc', refTemp.url);

           if(rtaParam != null)
               downloadFileFromServer(rtaParam);
           return;
       }
   }

   function getURLParams( name, url ) {
       try {
           if (!url)
               url = location.href;
           name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
           var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
           var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
           var results = regex.exec(url);
           return results == null ? null : results[1];
       } catch (e) {
           showSMS(e);
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

After create a download method

```
function downloadFileFromServer(fileServerURL){
try {
    var Downloader = window.plugins.Downloader;
    var fileName = fileServerURL.substring(fileServerURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    var downloadSuccessCallback = function(result) {
          console.log(result.path); 

    };

    var downloadErrorCallback = function(error) {
        // error: string
        console.log(error);
    };

    //TODO cordova.file.documentsDirectory for iOS

    var options = {
        title: 'Descarga de '+ fileName, // Download Notification Title
        url: fileServerURL, // File Url
        path: fileName, // The File Name with extension
        description: 'La descarga del archivo esta lista', // Download description Notification String
        visible: true, // This download is visible and shows in the notifications while in progress and after completion.
        folder: "Download" // Folder to save the downloaded file, if not exist it will be created
    };

    Downloader.download(options, downloadSuccessCallback, downloadErrorCallback);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

}

you can get the plugin here https://github.com/ogarzonm85/cordova-plugin-downloader

it Works and was too easy