# Find downloaded file from cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Using `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` I'm able to download files. But how can I access those files outside the application? It's a pdf. I open the iBook app but I can't find the file I just finished downloading. I believe it has something to do with the download path.

Can someone help me figure this out?

This is what I've done to download the file: [Cordova / Ionic - Download file from InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896026/cordova-ionic-download-file-from-inappbrowser)

Thank you :]

Comment: when you download a file you can get the url where it was downloaded (read the doc), and then you can use a file opener plugin to open it in another app (you can't force to use ibook, but the user can choose)

Comment: I know I can't force the user, i'm actually using the url provided to open the pdf in InAppBrowser, but I want to the file available for the user to view it later.

Comment: It will be available in your app. If you want it available in another app you have to use a file opener plugin and the user has to manually choose the other app and then the file will be in the other app for view it later

Comment: But there is no way it can be found with a file explorer app or something?

Comment: no, ios apps can only access their own sandbox

Comment: Ok, thanks @jcesarmobile. That's all I needed to know then :)